# Make default driver recognize lower screen resolutions 11.10?

Tags: display, xrandr

My laptop relies on intel 815 video chip. This is very problematic video card. None of my games under wine runs after the upgrade to 11.10. So I installed synaptic and removed the package that provided drivers for the video card(intel 8xx xorg). Unfortunately, the only screen resolution available for me after doing this, is 1024x768. I would love to have the ability to resize to 800x600(which is supported when the driver is installed.
Is there something I can try to do that. Anyone willing to help?

Comment: I think you are going to be better off configuring the intel driver then removing it.

Comment: I installed the unstable drivers from xorg-edgers, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The op resolved the issue by installing the unstable drivers from xorg-edgers

> I installed the unstable drivers from xorg-edgers, and this fixed it.